# How can this Data Access Code Lose Data?

Tags: linq

I´m using a Wcf service and in the data access layer I use this code:

```
public BindingList getPeople(s)
{
    IQueryable<Personal> query;
    EntidadesDataContext dc = GetDC();
    DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOptions.LoadWith<People>(pp=> pp.PeopleDepartment);
    loadOptions.LoadWith<PeopleDepartment>(pd=> pd.Department); // is what I lose in the UI
    dc.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
    query = from people in dc.People select people;

    return QueryToBindingList(query);
}
```

this code returns the data complete and exactly as I want, then I call it from the service and adding it to a `BindingList`

```
peopleBindingList = currentConnection.ServiceClient.People_GetPeople();
```

at peopleBindingList I lose the department values .... for example...

```
peopleBindingList.Select(pp=>pp.PeopleDepartament.First().Departament) ... returns Null
```

I check first that it's data to return...

Comment: This obviously has nothing to do with WCF. Which data access technology are you using? Linq to Entities? Linq to SQL?

Comment: I'm sorry .... I'm using Linq to Entities ...

Comment: Deleted duplicate; don't repost please - simply edit the existing one. Note that not everyone is awake at the same time; please be patient.

Comment: `DataLoadOptions` is LINQ-to-SQL, not EF (LINQ-to-Entities)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's my first time here, and I was not shure about what to do...thanks

Comment: I suspect that your implementation of the QueryToBindingList doesn't do a deep traversal of the child objects.

Answer (score 0):

> then I call it from the service

I bet you have a property that is not making across the service boundary!  Check the serialization of the types involved.  If you're using the DataContract serializer, make sure all properties you want are decorated with DataMember attributes.